# getElementById().value returning null asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc, null

I'm new to asp.net mvc and I'm trying to create filters for my charts.I have useds several buttons for that.

```html
@using Common
@model DateModel
<div>
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
<div>
    <p>

    </p>
</div>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<script>


    var dates = [@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.dates))];
    var DeletedCount = [@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.DeletedCount))];
    var ApprovedCount = [@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.ApprovedCount))];
    var ClosedCount = [@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.ClosedCount))];
    var OngoingCount = [@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.OngoingCount))];
    var NewCount = [@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.NewCount))];
    var ToBeAccepetdCount = [@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.ToBeAccepetdCount))];


    const data = {
        labels: dates[0],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Deleted',
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
            borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
            data: DeletedCount[0],
        },
            {
                label: 'Approved',
                backgroundColor: 'rgb(0,192, 0)',
                borderColor: 'rgb(0,192, 0)',
                data: ApprovedCount[0],
            },
            {
                label: 'Closed',
                backgroundColor: 'rgb(128, 128, 128)',
                borderColor: 'rgb(128,128, 128)',
                data: ClosedCount[0],
            },
            {
                label: 'Ongoing',
                backgroundColor: 'rgb(0, 32, 255)',
                borderColor: 'rgb(0, 32, 255)',
                data: OngoingCount[0],
            },
            {
                label: 'New',
                backgroundColor: 'rgb(80, 208, 255)',
                borderColor: 'rgb(80, 208, 255)',
                data: NewCount[0],
            },
            {
                label: 'To be Accepted',
                backgroundColor: 'rgb(90, 255, 128)',
                borderColor: 'rgb(90, 255, 128)',
                data: ToBeAccepetdCount[0],
            },

        ]
    };

    const config = {
        type: 'line',
        data: data,
        options: {
            responsive: true,
            plugins: {
                legend: {
                    position: 'top',
                },
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: 'Tasks'
                }
            },

            scales: {
                y: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                    ,
                    title: {
                        display: true,
                        text: 'Count'
                    }
                }
            }

        },

    };
</script>
<script>
    const myChart = new Chart(
        document.getElementById('myChart'),
        config
    );
</script>

<div align="center">
    <form method="POST">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-light" onclick="Today()">Today</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-light">Last 7 Days</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-light">This Month</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-light">Last Month</button>
        <script>
            function Today() {
                document.getElementById('sdate').value = '2022-02-01';
                document.getElementById('edate').value = @DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");;
                console.log(document.getElementById('sdate').value);
                console.log(document.getElementById('edate').value);
            }
        </script>
    </form>
 
</div>


<hr />

<div class="row">

    <form method="POST">
        <label for="sdatelbl">Start Date</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="@ViewBag.Sdate" id="sdate" name="sdate" value="" size="10" maxlength="10" />
        <label for="edatel">End Date</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=@ViewBag.Edate id="edate" name="edate" value="" size="15" maxlength="30" />
        <br>


        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="" value="Refresh">
    </form>
</div>
```

[Today Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alsjY.png)

When I click this I want to change **sdata** value in another form which is used as the cutom filter.But When I click the button it print the correct value in console,But returns null in home controller.

[console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0q1q.png)
[Homecontroller Index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSNKy.png)

How can I get the correct value in homecontroller?

Comment: I expect that you click the Today button and it submits the POST request to Controller. Well, if you check the form (that wrap the Today button), there is no input elements with `sDate` and `eDate`, so you will submit both value as empty. Thinking that you need to trigger the form with Refresh button.

Comment: @YongShun Still giving null value

Comment: @YongShun, yes that's the problem.  To trigger it without refresh button should I move these buttons inside the 'refresh' form?

Comment: Depend on your design, 1st approach is as you mentioned, move those buttons in the Refresh form (share the same form). 2nd approach (you want stick to current design), then you need to provide both input element as hidden (most important is provide the name attribute). `<input type="hidden" name="sDate" class="sDate" />` You may switch to use class instead for id as HTML element is with unique id. Hence, when you click Today button to assign today date to input element, you need to assign the value to input element with same class name: `sDate`. Same goes for `eDate` logic.